# DNS - txt and spf records (php mail())

Tags: php, email, dns, spf

i have a .no domain on www.syse.no and i have a hosting on us.lt. The problem is, i am unalbe to send mail letters using php mail() function. All emails go to spam. I red on php.net that i have to configure my txt and spf records but i have no idea how to do that. Maybe some one could help me?

Comment: it won't solve this specific problem, but I strongly recommend using a decent PHP class like PPHMailer instead of the crusty old `mail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

In the DNS entries of your domain www.syse.no you need to add an SPF record containing the IP address of your hosting on us.lt.

Answer (score 0):

Add an SPF record or update the existing SPF record in DNS for the domain you're using.  Assuming the domain is `syse.no`, then the new SPF record should be:

```
v=spf1 include:spf.tornado-mail.com include:us.lt ~all
```

This will add us.lt servers as allowed email sources for emails from this domain and preserve the existing authenticated email sources.